# how Object.keys(obj) works?

Tags: javascript

As per the [description of the `Object.keys` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

> Object.keys returns an array whose elements are strings corresponding to the enumerable properties found directly upon object. **The ordering of the properties is the same as that given by looping over the properties of the object manually.**

It includes the following example:

```
// array like object with random key ordering
var an_obj = { 100: "a", 2: "b", 7: "c"};

alert(Object.keys(an_obj)); // will alert "2, 7, 100"
```

But as per the definition, key should be printed as `100, 2, 7` in the order they have been inserted in the object, instead of `2, 7, 100`.

Please let me know, how the ordering of key happens in `Object.key`.

Comment: Have you tried "looping over the properties of the object manually", to confirm your theory that you would get them in the order `100,2,7` rather than `2,7,100`?

Comment: "as per the definition" - what definition? the one above? It says nothing about insertion order.

Comment: Keys of JavaScript objects, like other HashTable/Dictionary structures, are unordered.  If you want to maintain order, you need to use an array or similar structure.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev,  I have highlighted it in bold

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you might have misunderstood this:

> The ordering of the properties is the same as that given by looping over the properties of the object manually.

What this means is that the order of the properties in Object.keys is the same as if you did a for-in loop.

Compare the results of these:

```
var an_obj = { 100: "a", 2: "b", 7: "c"};

//using object.keys...
console.log(Object.keys(an_obj));

//using a manual loop...
for(var k in an_obj) { console.log(k); }
```

You will find the order for both these is the same.

Comment: +1 "manually" is a poor term for MDN to use here. There are different ways to loop manually. They should have specifically stated `for-in`.

Comment: @JanDvorak: No, I don't edit MDN. Correct information is constantly being replaced with incorrect information. It's not worth the time.

Comment: @niran The order of the object keys is not guaranteed. This basically depends on the browser implementation. If you need a guaranteed order, you need to use arrays.

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript objects are unordered key-value pairs. `Object.keys` returns an array of the keys of the object in the order they would be returned if you were to iterate over them, but it makes no guarantees over the order of the result in relation to the order of insertion.

Answer (score 2):

Objects are by definition (See specification: http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm ) unordered. So no matter how you did the input, there is no guarantee of the order of the keys. If you wish to maintain the order, you should keep a seperate list with the order of the keys.

Answer (score 1):

I am explaining a bit more about the difference between these :

```
Object.keys(obj)
```

```
for(var key in obj){
    console.log(key);
}
```

**Similarity :**

Both returns keys in same order. Not a single difference between these.

**Explanation:**

1. If you have numeric keys in your object then

   - All numeric keys comes in natural ordering.
   - All other keys comes in insertion order.
2. If object does not contain any numeric key then insertion order will be followed by both the tricks.

**Example:**

```
var sec_obj = {0:"0", "d":23, "r": "a", "a": "b", "7": "c","z":23, 23:23};

//using object.keys...
console.log(Object.keys(sec_obj));

//using a manual loop...
for(var k in sec_obj) { console.log(k); }
```

**Result**

```
["0", "7", "23", "d", "r", "a", "z"]
0
7
23
d
r
a
z
```

Answer (score -1):

It’s important to mention the limitations of [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), as MDN article does. It recommends to use [`getOwnPropertyNames`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames). MDN articles also show browser support.